# .htaccess not rewriting for missing www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need all non-www requests to redirect to www. I believe I'm doing this right, but this code is not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on  

# If www is missing from the beginning of the URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

UPDATE:

I thought the answer was here: http://www.jarrodoberto.com/articles/2011/11/enabling-mod-rewrite-on-ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu and my default site did not have AllowOverride to to All in areas shown below:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All                                 <- HERE
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All                                 <- HERE
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I was hoping that after an Apache restart the problem would be resolved, but I'm still not seeing a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION

It seems that the problem was a mis-configuration in my vhost setup file:

**This is wrong.** Notice that the ServerName is set to www.mysite.com and the ServerAlias is set to www-prod.mysite.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias www-prod.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/.../html_www
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/.../html_www>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/...-access_log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/...-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

**This is right.** The ServerName and ServerAlias need to be set as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/.../html_www
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/.../html_www>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/...-access_log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/...-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

In my defense, this was not configured by me. I think our other developer was attempting to do something tricky with the server alias.

Comment: Actually, looking at this, should these be the other way around? ServerName = www.mysite.com and ServerAlias = mysite.com?